# emacs fix tab indentation for python

Tags: tabs, indentation, emacs24, python-mode

Emacs tab indentation in python mode is using tab instead of 4-spaces.

My emacs init.el file contains:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode t)
(setq-default tab-width 4)
(setq indent-line-function 'insert-tab)
```

I have tried:

```
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
```

but it didn't make any difference. 
Using `white-space` mode in emacs I see that tab does NOT indent 4-white-spaces and `untabify` fixes the tab to 4-white-spaces. How do I make TAB to work as four white-spaces?

**UPDATE**
fixed by changing init.el config to:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
        (setq-default tab-width 4)
        (setq-default python-indent 4)))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert TABs, indent-tabs-mode must be `t'. Change that in hook shown.
Write

```
(setq indent-tabs-mode t)
```

Seems python.el has a bug, when setting it to nil alongside with mode. As hooks run after the mode init, it should be able to correct that.

If not, try python-mode.el, which permits choice.
Also you can set indent-tabs-mode, which is made buffer-local by python.el, in every buffer explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Though it's late, following hooks worked for me.
Only spaces

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (setq indent-tabs-mode nil)
        (setq python-indent 4)
        (setq tab-width 4))
      (untabify (point-min) (point-max)))
```

Only tabs

```
 (add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq indent-tabs-mode t)
            (setq python-indent 4)
            (setq tab-width 4))
          (tabify (point-min) (point-max)))
```